# Why iOS has no error responder chain built in?

Tags: ios, error-handling

According to [Apple's Error Handling Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/ErrorRespondRecover/ErrorRespondRecover.html), there exist **Error Responder Chain** in AppKit, that `NSResponder` with `willPresentError:` and `NSApplicationDelegate` with `application:willPresentError:`, etc.

But in iOS, UIKit is lack of the architecture to do this. I found an open sourced project [ErrorKit](https://github.com/hectr/ErrorKit/) implemented the error responder chain but just wondering why Apple didn't provide the support at framework level. Or is there any other suggested way to do error-handling in iOS?

Comment: Damn good question sir